# Interleave random numbers

Tags: random, objective-c++, c++03

I would like to interleave a random number with some alphanumeric characters, for example: HELLO mixed with the random number 25635 → `H2E5L6L3O5`. I know `%1d` controls the spacing, although I'm not sure how to interleave text between the random numbers or how accomplish this.

Code:

```
int main(void) {
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

        printf("%1d", 0 + (rand() % 10)); 

        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

btw - if my random number generator isn't very good i'm open to suggestions - thanks

Comment: Do you want to generate the alphanumeric characters randomly also, or do you want them in a string?

Comment: @BlueIce, the characters wouldn't be random, just wedged in-between the random numbers. thx

Comment: Also, if you are using C++, you want `cout` instead of `printf()`.

Comment: @Blue Ice, I'm actually embedding this into obj-c, so unsure if cout will work.

Comment: Ah. It was tagged `c++`, not `objective-c`. That's why I made the recommendation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're okay with using C++11, you could use something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine e1(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(0, 9);

    std::string word = "HELLO";
    for (auto ch : word) {
        std::cout << ch << uniform_dist(e1);
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

...which produces e.g.:

```
H3E6L6L1O5
```

If you're stuck with an older compiler, you could use [`rand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) and [`srand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) from the standard C library for your random numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::srand(std::time(NULL));

    std::string word = "HELLO";
    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << word[i] << (rand() % 10);
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - is there any way to use this without the requirement of C++11?

Comment: @ctfd: I've added a version that uses `rand` -- is that what you were thinking of?

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific. It's the C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions] that I can't use.

Comment: @ctfd: ah, okay. I think I've edited out all the C++11 bits on the second example now.

Comment: awesome, thanks very much. it works great (and code is shorter too!) :) btw - congratz on hitting 10k!